# Is asking the e-banking username/password from a 3rd party site compliant with 3dsecure and PSD2?

Tags: authentication, password-management, account-security, multi-factor

Recently I tried to make an online purchase in one of the biggest e-commerce sites in Greece.

During checkout, and after providing debit card details, it **asked me to provide the username/password (not one-time-password) of my e-banking account to an iframe** inside the site.

I inspected the iframe url (src attribte) and it was again the e-commerce site's url. Only when clicking on login (with some test credentials) it performed a request towards the bank's site.

The above felt wrong and insecure to me.

After communicating my bank (one of the 4 biggest) to tell them that the e-commerce site does something that feels wrong related to e-banking, they insisted that this is how [3dsecure](https://docs.3dsecure.io/3dsv2/_downloads/b412903d6e2c99b7828246fa10db5b3e/EMVCo_3DS_Spec_v220.pdf) works and that this way they are compliant to [PSD2](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/payment-services-psd-2-directive-eu-2015-2366_en) directive that is obligatory from 1/1/2021.

The same response I got from the e-commerce site.

I really felt that my perception of security is far differrent than the bank's or the e-commerce site's?

I can't figure out:

- How can one know that they are really accessing the bank's site, when they click the button inside that iframe?
- And if one trusts the good intentions of the e-commerce site, how can they be sure that the e-commerce site does not suffer from a script injection vulnerability that would steal their e-banking username/password?

**Can someone help me understand whether the way that the above e-commerce site works is considered compatible to [3dsecure](https://docs.3dsecure.io/3dsv2/_downloads/b412903d6e2c99b7828246fa10db5b3e/EMVCo_3DS_Spec_v220.pdf) to [PSD2](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/payment-services-psd-2-directive-eu-2015-2366_en)**? If yes, does this mean that the latter 2 are insecure, or am I missing something?

P.S: I know that asking for [PSD2](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/payment-services-psd-2-directive-eu-2015-2366_en) specifically may be considered off-topic, since it is actually a legislative directive, but I think it might be equally off-topic in [law.stackexchange.com](https://law.stackexchange.com/) as too technical.

([PSD2 law details](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32015L2366&from=EN))

Comment: The form's "action" attribute should show where your login info is being sent.  The form fields can be grabbed via javascript running in the same domain... so the iframe's src should be your bank and not the e-commerce site.  (Hopefully the form in this case is inside another nested iframe?)